# MVC, Jquery.Ajax: How to return a partial view with nested partial view datatable?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Using jquery.ajax, I am trying to return a view, that has a nested partial view to display a datatable.   The initial view is returning, but the datatable is not showing or rendering.

### AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Controller/Action,
        data: {
            custNum: custNum
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#DivToRenderResults').html(data);
        }
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult Action(string custNum)
       {
            Model ReturnModel = GetData(custNum)

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView(ReturnModel);
            }
            return View(ReturnModel );
        }
```

### Model

```
public class Model
{
    public FirstViewsModel FirstViewsModel {get;set;)
    public IEnumerable<DataTableModel> DataTableModel {get;set}
}
```

I ultimately want to use ajax to dynamically load different tabs that all will have nested datatables in partial views, but I am unable to get this first one to work.   Please help, & thank you!

### Target View

```
  <div id="DivToRenderResults">
  <\div>

// Inside the div
@model Model
<div>
    // FirstViewModelInfo

      <div>
          // This one is not rendering in the return
          @Html.Partial("_DataTableView", Model)
      </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: is your action being called?

Comment: How do you trigger your AJAX request?

Comment: check RenderPartialViewToString

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad Yes, I am able to verify the action is being called when ajax is submitted.

Comment: @Jasen The trigger is a button click

Comment: Is the success handler executing? Does `data` contain the view's html? Does `$("#DivToRenderResults")` actually find its target? What do the views look like?

Comment: Using firebug I see that the data I am requesting is in the "Response" tab of my console data, but the "HTML" tab only shows the initial views model.  I am not sure how to debug if $("#DivToRenderResults") actually finds its target.  I will mark up the view

Comment: Try renaming data parameter of success to some other name

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I just tried renaming "data" to "result" and gave it a go.  Still no change.

Comment: remove # sign from div id in html that's the mistake

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad  My apologies, the example had that typo, but that is not currently an issue in my project.  I assume you were referring to the id under "Target View" <div id="DivToRenderResults">.  I edited the sample so its removed.

Comment: _I am not sure how to debug if $("#DivToRenderResults") actually finds its target._ Try `console.log($("#DivToRenderResults").size(), data)`